# (Mongoose) Failed to remove a TTL field

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a authentication system where the user need to validate their email after creating an account, then the status of the account would change from Pending to Active.

I want to implement a feature that if a user does not validate their email within a time frame, the account will be deleted. I was able to get the delete part done by setting an expire field in the Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IUser>(
    {
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            default: "Pending",
            required: true,
        },
        expiresAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: () => Date.now() + 30 * 1000,
            expires: 30
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
```

However, the expire counter seem to be still counting even I purposely deleted the `expiresAt` field, and the document still get deleted.

```
const user = await User.findById(tokenId).exec();

user.status = 'Active';
user.expiresAt = undefined;
const updatedUser = await user.save();
```

I wonder is there a way to stop or remove the TTL feature entirely after validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a feature provide by the `mongoose` schema, You are not actually deleting the `expiresAt` value, the `mongoose` schema ignored that input as it does not match the type.

By looking at `mongoose` source code we can see this:

doc: `{ status: "Active", expiredAt: undefined }`

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj);
let i = keys.length;
while (i--) {
  key = keys[i];
  val = obj[key];

  if (obj[key] === void 0) {
    delete obj[key];
    continue;
  }
}
```

The expressions `obj[key] === void 0` means if `obj[key] === undefined` like in your case, basically `mongoose` removes this value from the update body.

What you want to do is just use an operator like `$unset`:

```
db.collection.updateOne({ _id: user._id}, {$set: {status: "Active"}, $unset: {expiresAt: ""}})
```

Comment: The issue remained, it still get deleted after 30s

Comment: After a few testing, I found out something weird, even I changed the ```expiresAt``` field from 30s to 300s, it get deleted at around 60s, obviously something wrong with my code, I need to check

Comment: At the end of the day, the problem originates from the fact that I didn't manually remove the TTL index from the mongodb before making changes to the javascript code; otherwise, the collections would still be holding the 30s index. Consequently, the problem is resolved when I clear the collections' index and apply the changes.